How can I install XAMPP onto SteamOS?
I've been trying the whole day to install XAMPP onto my Steam Deck so that I can run Apache and other things from the XAMPP Control Panel.
I've gone to the XAMPP website and downloaded XAMPP for Linux. The download gives me a .run file, but how do I run this .run file?
When I open the file, then I get the following:

What app do I need to choose to install XAMPP? I've chosen a couple of random ones, but it's not working.
Launching it using the default Discover app, I get the following error:

Could not open file:///home/deck/Downloads/xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks.

EDIT: As suggested by ZOOM in the comments. I need to try and run it through the Terminal using the following command:
./xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run, but that gives a permission error:

bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run: Permission denied

And running . ./xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run, gives the following error:

bash: .: ./xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run: cannot execute binary file


Open/Start a Terminal
Ctrl+Alt+T
or
Ctrl+Alt+F1 or F2, etc..
How to Open the Terminal on the Steam Deck
How we open the Terminal on SteamOS ? 
Login as root or sudo and run:
How can I find out what my sudo password is on SteamOS?
Before you can run the installer, you need to make it executable:
Switch to Downloads:
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run
or
sudo . ./xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run
Once installed run:
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Manually Start LAMP Server
XAMPP Control Panel run:
sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start
Linux Frequently Asked Questions XAMPP FAQ's
How to start the XAMPP control panel on Fedora 27?
How to start xampp control panel on linux through terminal
Ubuntu 16.04 - How to start xampp control panel
Cannot execute binary file
Check if you run the correct version of XAMPP for your system architecture (64-bit).
SteamOS is based on Arch Linux, thios version of XAMPP should work normally.
Check this posts for "cannot execute binary file":
Linux Version Officially Released 
Has Anyone Installed An AMP (Apache,MySQL,PHP) Stack On Deck? 
distrobox
Neither Steam (Native) or Steam (Runtime) run on Garuda
Try to open a terminal with:
Why does this binary executable give “cannot execute: required file not found”?
Install the packages individually
I'm not sure how much experience you have, but if the normal way doesn't work, try installing Apache, PHP, and MariaDB separately.
Try it with Docker
If possible, you could get Docker running, and then it wouldn't be a problem to run it through that.
Setup docker on the steamdeck
linuxserver/steamos
SteamOS VSCode + Docker guide
Edit:

managed to install it, but I'm not able to open XAMPP. Running sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start doesn't open it. Seems to fail. Lots of command not found warning


Check installation directory


ls /opt/lampp


Check and edit executable permission


sudo chmod +x /opt/lampp/lampp


Try to run again with


sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start


Check the logs


sudo cat /opt/lampp/logs/error_log


Set the path


export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin


If the installation directory is missing or incomplete,reinstall


I did the "Switch to Downloads" solution that you posted to install it, but now I'm not sure how to run it. How do I open the XAMPP Control Panel?
